# How to copy a logo from an image

Tags: user-interface, adobe, photoshop

Is it possible to copy a logo from an image.I have an image and i wanna copy logo of the image.

The Image url is here --

```
 [1]: https://dribbble.com/shots/3354720-Login-splash-screen-ZAD-App-iOS/attachments/728266
```

How can i acheive this thing.Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can. Use the Magic wand tool and click the logo, then press and hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and click any other parts of the logo that are not selected.
You have now selected the image. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, open a new document or new layer and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn it into a mask, which is less messy than using the magic wand tool. Look in the channels panel, select the channel with the highest contrast and copy it to a mask channel. Use levels to blacken the blacks and whiten the whites without touching the grays.
Now you can apply the mask to an adjustment layer or image, fill a new layer with a color etc. and apply the mask.

Answer (score -1):

Save yourself the time and use Adobe Illustrator's option to trace an image. Way better then all these suggestions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).